elasticsearch node ids changed after changing dockercompose file
I have an Elasticsearch cluster configured in a docker compose file.
The cluster has three nodes, all running on the same host. In each node I have a docker volume (not pinned) that is mapped to /usr/share/elasticsearch/data folder inside the node.
I wanted to move the data of two of the nodes to a different drive on the host, so I copied the folders from /var/lib/docker/volumes to the different drive, and changed the volume defintion under the nodes to be defined insead of:
`volumes:

data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data`

to:
`volumes:

/media/some_drive/data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data`

When I started the cluster again, it failed to assign some of the indexes because their master shard couldn't be allocated. So I tried running curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true which failed bacuse it couldn't find the indexes.
In hindsight, there was a _data folder inside the folders I copied from the docker volumes folder, and I think this is the actual volume that was used by docker, so I had to map that to the volume and not the containing folder.
I decided to try to put everything back into stable state and rething my plan. So I copied the folders back to the docker volumes folder in the original place, reverted the volumes config in the docker compose file and started the cluster.
The cluster failed to start, when I looked at the logs, it said that elasticsearch failed to elect a master node because it was waiting for nodes with some IDs, but the existing nodes IDs are different.
The volumes' size looks correct, so I hope the data is not lost.
Is there anything I can do?

Node IDs are generated when a node believes it has been started for the very first time, based on an empty data directory. I cannot tell you exactly what went wrong without examining the data, but one possible scenario is that your data directory was mounted at the wrong level. For example, the data might be in usr/share/elasticsearch/data/data or something similar. Before you experiment further, I suggest making copies of all volumes in their current state. These manipulations carry a high risk of losing your data.

@imotov Thank you. I'm doing a copy of these values right now. If the mounted data folder was changed in a node, would it still keep the id it chose or will it use the id in the data folder?

After you have copies try attaching to one of the nodes with a new id and check the content of the usr/share/elasticsearch/data. If you see another data directory there then my hunch might be correct. If not, it really depends on the version of elasticsearch that you are using there were significant changes between 7.x and 8.x for example.
